# how to solve this problem for passing arguments in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to pass 2 arguments from 'getCodePage' to 'MainPage' then i have this error.
this is my getCodePage the part that i pass the arguments:

```
onTap: (){
                    final String NumID = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments.toString();
                    final SmsCode = _controller.text;
                    final IDNum = NumID.toString();
                    final url = 'https://***********/api/User/$IDNum?sms=$SmsCode';
                    Future fetchSMS() async {
                      final response = await http.get(url);
                      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                        return jsonDecode(response.body);
                      } else {
                        throw Exception('Failed');
                      }
                    }
                    fetchSMS().then((resaultOfFeture) {
                      final args = {
                        'rof' : resaultOfFeture,
                        'idNum' : IDNum, 
                      };
                      if(resaultOfFeture == true){
                        final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('با موفقیت وارد شدید',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: "IranSans",
                              fontSize: 18
                          ),
                        ),
                        );
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => MainPage(),
                          settings: RouteSettings(
                            arguments: args
                          ),
                        ));

                      }else{
                        final snackBar1 = SnackBar(content: Text('کد اشتباه وارد شده',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: "IranSans",
                              fontSize: 18
                          ),
                        ),
                        );
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar1);
                      }
                    });

                  },
```

and this my mainPage when I want get my arguments as object:

```
final logedUser = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    final data = logedUser['rof'];
```

then I have that error here:
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object' flutter error

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the arguments you are passing to `MainPage` in `didChangeDependencies`

something like this

`MainPage.dart`

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const route = "/main-page";
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {


  var args;
  var data; 

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    if (args != ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments) {
      args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
      data = args["rof"]; 
    }

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it calls me back null always! even with textfield value!

Comment: The null error: The method '[]' was called on null.